# PHP Prepopulate Dropdown from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Am creating a table whose values are populated from a two dimensional array as shown below using php's for loop. But unable to populate the drop-down based on the value from the array because I couldn't figure out a correct way to insert the below php code inside the echo which selects the option based on a condition,

```
  <option value='0' if ($result[$row]['discount'] == '0') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> >0</option>

<?php

$result = array (

    array (
      'item' => 'Dextrose', 
      'price' => '10.00',
      'quantity' => '10',
      'discount' => '5.00',
      'total' => '95.00'
      ),

    array (
      'item' => 'Nescaine',
      'price' => '20.00',
      'quantity' => '30',
      'discount' => '10.00',
      'total' => '540.00'
      ),

    array (
      'item' => 'Anticavity',
      'price' => '30.00',
      'quantity' => '10',
      'discount' => '25.00',
      'total' => '225.00'
     )
  );


for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($result); $row++)

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='item[]' value=".$result[$row]['item']." required></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' value=".$result[$row]['price']." required></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' value=".$result[$row]['quantity']." required></td>";
    echo "<td><select name='discount[]' >
              <option value='0'".if($result[$row]['discount'] == '0') echo 'selected = "selected"'.">0</option>
              <option value='5'".if($result[$row]['discount'] == '5') echo 'selected = "selected"'.">5</option>
              <option value='10'".if($result[$row]['discount'] == '10') echo 'selected = "selected"'.">10</option>
              <option value='25'".if($result[$row]['discount'] == '25') echo 'selected = "selected"'.">25</option></td>";
    echo "<td><input name='total[]' value=".$result[$row]['total']." ></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<br>";        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting `echo` in-front of each HTML line. You can use PHP closing and opening braces to achieve it easily.

You can update your PHP code like this,

```
<?php
for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($result); $row++)
{
?> 
<tr>
   <td><input type='text' name='item[]' value="<?php echo $result[$row]['item']; ?>" required></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='price[]' value="<?php echo $result[$row]['price']; ?>" required></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' value="<?php echo $result[$row]['quantity']; ?>" required></td>
   <td><select name='discount[]' >
              <option value='0' <?php if($result[$row]['discount'] == '0') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>0</option>
              <option value='5' <?php if($result[$row]['discount'] == '5') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>5</option>
              <option value='10' <?php if($result[$row]['discount'] == '10') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>10</option>
              <option value='25' <?php if($result[$row]['discount'] == '25') { ?> selected <?php } ?>>25</option></td>
   <td><input name='total[]' value= <?php echo $result[$row]['total']; ?>></td>";
   </tr><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors on your code:

Line 1 - before "`if`" insert:  "`<?php`"

Bellow, replace your "IF's":

```
if($result[$row]['discount'] == '0') echo 'selected = "selected"'
```

with this constructor:

```
($result[$row]['discount'] == '0' ? 'selected = "selected" : '')
```

Hope this helps.